# How should we handle rude edit summaries?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, offensive, edit-summary

If someone is rude or offensive in a comment, that can be flagged easily. What should be done if a user makes a valid edit in the [Suggested Edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review), however is rude or offensive in the Edit Summary describing the edit?

The post that got me thinking's story went something like this

- New user posts a question with missing tag needed for proper audience - forgivable as they're new to the system
- Existing user edits to add tag - helpful
- Edit summary could be considered offensive - unhelpful

What should be done in a situation like this?

Comment: Would it be possible to link to the post/edit in question?

Comment: Click on improve and uncheck the "this edit is helpful" checkbox

Comment: I'm not ashamed to say that I've rejected more than a few edits solely for the fact that the edit summary does not accurately summarize the edit. This includes edits with rude summaries.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229325/how-to-deal-with-inappropriate-comments-attached-to-edits

Comment: Just about everything "could be considered offensive" to somebody.  Did you mean "Edit summary is vulgar" or something instead?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/267246/5

Comment: I agree with @tmyklebu. Do you have any concrete examples?

Comment: I once got misunderstood by certain of people on the edit summary that I've made, If I were not mistaken it's implying like "Hey, be sure to fix your code next time. :)" Something like thaaat, and theen. Boom, peps tagging me like I'm being so rude. Got sad on that, not purposely did it. :(

Comment: @Cupcake: Reads tongue-in-cheek to me.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the edit summary does not adequately reflect the intention of the edit (in the absence of total obviousness), then simply reject it. Edits are a *great* teaching tool to help people that haven't learned how to communicate as well as the rest of us learn how to better articulate themselves.

Now, they don't need to be literary masterpieces, but .. they should be informative in the absence of an extremely obvious and simple change.

If there's snark, well, that's simply unhelpful noise. Don't mistake *honest* attempts at bringing a little humor to the table as snark, but stuff like "learn how to spell!" or "such a n00b" or anything of the like isn't something we want gracing our revision histories.

If you see a pattern of rudeness *anywhere* (including edit summaries), [flag it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging). You can flag the post (whether on the question or the answer) and select "In need of moderator attention", then provide a link to either the suggested edit or to the revision with the offensive edit summary (in case the suggested edit already got approved). A brief description on why you think it's rude/offensive might be helpful, if it isn't obvious.

Comment: `If there's snark, well, that's simply unhelpful noise.` Well... Maybe. In some cases I'd agree that "learn how to spell!" is kicking someone while they're down (they misspelled one thing, or a few things, but it wasn't intentional). But I don't think anyone genuinely believes the word "you" is spelled "u", "are" is spelled "r", or the empty string is spelled "^_^". It might just be that I enjoy being an embittered, cynical shell of a person too much to give it up now, but I do believe snark has value.

Comment: Over the years I've seen a lot of people drastically misspell the empty string, and I'm starting to think it might be intentional.

Comment: Given what edits are usually approved I doubt that rejecting such edits will do anything but annoy whoever rejected it, because he knows that it won't do anything because everyone else will approve it...

Comment: @tmyklebu Eugh. That's probably valid Scala syntax, but in the real world you can't just put two XOR operators on either side of an underscore and call it a day. It just won't compile. Hell, that kind of nonsense is probably illegal in Singapore. Along with chewing gum. And not serving in the armed forces. What a wonderful country...

Comment: @ParthianShot: For what it's worth, I saw chewing gum stuck to the sidewalk in Bugis a few years ago.  And a (single) piece of litter.  Also, I give you:  `int _ = 42; printf("%i\n", 8^_^8);`

Comment: ...Edit messages are generally not seen by the person whose content was edited, right?