# Banned a second time from reviewing for the same reviews as 3 months ago

Tags: bug, status-review, review-suspension

I just see I'm banned from reviewing for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33843628) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33850482). Both are from February.

[image]

We could think the ban is just late, but it's not as I already posted a question about an explanation about the reason for this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423212/10952503) (10k+ rep link), but in February, when I have been banned for those reviews...

Am I banned for the same reviews again, or does they should changed but it's not? If they are not the same, which one are they?

I would notice that even if I failed some review audit as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424278/10952503), since this one, I didn't fail any. I wasn't banned yesterday because of a failed audit.

Comment: Related reading: [Rude edit summaries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267215/rude-edit-summaries)

Comment: Also related: "[How can report an offensive edit summary?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424548/3773011)", which is where the edit summary in the suggested edit for which you were actually suspended from reviewing was reported.

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like a bug.  Our tools show that message you should be seeing is:

> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34318121
>
> For these reviews in the *Suggested edits* review queue, the *Reject and Edit* action would have been more appropriate. While the edit is good, the edit message is obviously not acceptable. You should've chosen *Reject and Edit* to apply the necessary edit to the post but without the inappropriate edit message. *Reject* would've been acceptable too, in case you were unsure about how to edit the post: the key point here is that the edit message should not have been approved.
>
> Being suspended can be a frustrating experience, but correct reviews help us maintain quality content on the site.
>
> In the meantime, you can refer to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits) for more information and revisit your recent reviews.

If you're instead seeing the message from February, could you describe any necessary reproduction steps?

Comment: That was a bit of a controversial edit though, @RyanM . The reason for the rejection (by a moderator after it was approved) was because of the summary's language (see related [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424548/2029983)), but the edit itself was good and has been reinstated. I'm not sure the OP should be review banned for it.

Comment: I suppose my question then, is should a reviewer be expected to reject good edits when the language of the summary is rude.

Comment: I just added a screen of what I see at https://stackoverflow.com/review (simply when clicking on the link to access to all review queues). Also, as Thom said, I accepted this edit because of the language. It remove the noise of the answer to only keep the import part: the code & the link. Banned only because of this review, is -for me- severe

Comment: @ThomA How to handle it is probably a reasonable meta question (I'm not the moderator that issued the review suspension), although separate from this one about why they're seeing a different message.  I'd suggest a moderator flag as the ideal approach, as moderators can change the message in the revision history.

Comment: A second attempt at Google-fu seems to suggest that rejection is likely the right option, with a flag ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267215/2029983), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364891/2029983)). So though the edit was good, the OP should have rejected it and flagged.

Comment: Thanks for information, I didn't know about this. But, the original post doesn't contains private informations, that's why I didn't flag. Also, actually, the result is exactly as after editing, even after Dharman's changes. As Thom said, it's a good edit but it's simply not the best choice. I understand, and sorry for this, but it's not too much severe ?

Comment: @ThomA even without googling the relevant MSO posts, should a reviewer be expected to *not* reject a good edit with a rude summary? If not, why? The edit summary, just like every other input field on the platform, is subject to the CoC.

Comment: @blackgreen we don't know if the person is already reported, suspended, limited into answer/question etc. Also, it's not "so much" rude, which can explain that no one between both edit reviewer, and we simply think with edit it's fixed

Comment: The edit itself is still good, @blackgreen , so approve and flag would also seem like an appropriate action. Here, however, such action would have got the user review banned still.

Comment: @blackgreen what ever the guidance is, the submitter of the review should be dealt with, not the reviewers. Mods jumped on it. That is not good.

Comment: @rene I completely disagree that the reviewers should not be dealt with. Not dealing with the reviewers would imply that approving abuse in suggested edit messages is fine. It’s obviously *not* fine. I don’t know why you think that reviewers are free of responsibility here.

Comment: @ThomA approving and flagging might be sort of acceptable, at the very least it makes moderators aware of something that needs follow up with the user who suggested the edit. However it’s a worse solution since a moderator who sees the review task might not see the flag

Comment: @blackgreen awesome, you can answer my meta question then: [Should reviewers who don’t reject a rude review comment be review suspended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424566)